# How to hit a local fastify route when a react component executes `fetch`? Is it possible?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, fastify

I have the following setup:

- Fastify server
- Renders a React App using SSR
- Some React components use `fetch`
- Some fetch commands hit the same server (i.e. /api/listitem)

I can swap `fetch` for something custom with the same signature, but would like to avoid a network loopback.

Is it possible?